# Change User Agent of AWS SDK in Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

Is it possible to change the user-agent of AWS SDK services when we initiate services such as S3 or IAM? The reason is that using the SDK any activities from my application will be logged as "Java 1.8.....". Instead of that, I would like to change it to "Awesome Apps".

My code is something like this

```
public static AmazonS3 initS3() throws IOException{
    InputStream input = AWSS3.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("awscred.properties");
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
    BasicAWSCredentials  credentials  = new BasicAWSCredentials(prop.getProperty("provider.aws01.username"), prop.getProperty("provider.aws01.password"));
    AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
    return s3Client;
}
public static AmazonIdentityManagement initIAM() throws IOException{
    InputStream input = AWSIAM.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("awscred.properties"); //entah kenapa ga muncul resources disini ga langsung kedetect
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    prop.load(input);
    BasicAWSCredentials  credentials  = new BasicAWSCredentials(prop.getProperty("provider.aws06.username"), prop.getProperty("provider.aws06.password"));
    AmazonIdentityManagement iam = AmazonIdentityManagementClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).build();
    return iam;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it can be done with ClientConfiguration. Here is an example for S3:

```
public static AmazonS3 initS3() throws IOException{
        ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
        config.setUserAgentPrefix("CloudRAID Management");
        config.setUserAgentSuffix("006b8507-b815-47b9-bce0-08b91981f17a");

        InputStream input = AWSS3.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("awscred.properties");
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        prop.load(input);
        BasicAWSCredentials  credentials  = new BasicAWSCredentials(prop.getProperty("provider.aws01.username"), prop.getProperty("provider.aws01.password"));
        AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().withRegion(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1).withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials)).withClientConfiguration(config).build();

        return s3Client;

}
```

Comment: is there any way to change the default user-agent without changing the source code, like setting jvm properties and likes? Thanks

Comment: @Rodel not sure, I was thinking the same thing but could not find any info about this. Could be a new question perhaps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I just need to update the source code supporting the user-agent